# Minha regex não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

Eu fiz uma expressão regular para celular, no site https://regex101.com/ está dando certo, mas no meu projeto não, segue abaixo o exemplo

Meu pattern no código: `telefone: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(\(\d{2}\)\ \d{1}\ \d{4}\-\d{4})')]]`

String utilizada para teste no site https://regex101.com/ : `(00) 0 0000-0000`

[image: print do site https://regex101.com/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `pattern` está recebendo uma string, e dentro de strings o caractere `\` deve ser escapado e escrito como `\\`. Então ficaria:

```
Validators.pattern("\\(\\d{2}\\) \\d \\d{4}-\\d{4}")
```

Além disso, repare que o espaço e o hífen não precisam do `\` antes, e o quantificador `{1}` é desnecessário, pois `\d{1}` é o mesmo que `\d`.

Também retirei os parênteses em volta da expressão, que não parecem fazer diferença aqui.

---

Outra alternativa é usar a sintaxe literal de regex, delimitando-a por barras, assim você não precisa escapar a `\`:

```
Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{2}\) \d \d{4}-\d{4}$/)
```

Incluí os marcadores `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e fim da string. No primeiro caso não precisa, pois [segundo a documentação](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern), ao passar uma string, esses marcadores são adicionados automaticamente.